# Best way to store bookmarks MYSQL, PHP

Tags: mysql, performance

I was recently thinking which way is the best to store bookmarks and thought i will ask this question on here:

Method 1(this is the simple and most used way):

```
+-------------------+
| bookmarks_users   |
|-------------------|
| id (int, primary) |
| user_id (int)     |
| bookmark_id (int) |
+-------------------+
```

Method 2:

```
+-------------------+
| bookmarks_users   |
|-------------------|
| id (int, primary) |
| user_id (int)     |
| bookmarks_ids (int) |
+-------------------+
```

but instead of having it multiple we can have one row per user and each time they add a bookmark we can just put it in `bookmarks_ids` so it will look like this `1,21,35,223,677,345,653,566,244`
and on the user side we can just use php to split them based on the `,` and then fetch all the posts via another function

Comment: @mustaccio Hay, nice thanks for sharing this info with me.

Comment: Can a bookmark be shared between users?

Comment: @RickJames well generally from what I see bookmarks are more of a personal thing rather than sharing but it might be a good feature to implement

Comment: you will just have to create a duplicate of the bookmarks and assign the user_id to who you are sharing to.

Comment: The `Bookmarks` table would have a `user_id` and the info about the bookmark.  This is the "many-to-one" pattern.  There is no extra table; that is for many-to-many.